# Confusion with に、を、と particles used with verbs like 感じる

Tags: grammar, nuances, particles

Consider this sentence:

> 私は試験のために勉強しなかったことが残念**に**感じる。I feel regret that I didn't study for the exam.

`1.`Why is the に particle used instead of と?

I have read the answer to [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8278/is-%E6%84%9F%E3%81%98%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%93%E3%81%98%E3%82%8B-transitive-or-intransitive-which-particle-to-use) which considers how 感じる can be used with the を, と and に particles under different circumstances. But I still have trouble understanding it.

In this part of the answer:

> "4. When it appears to take に, the に particle is actually marking an adverb. This happens with transitive and intransitive uses of the verb."

I interpret this to mean that 残念に would be translated as "regrettably" into an adverb. So 残念に感じる means "to feel regrettably". If I translated it literally: "I regrettably feel that I didn't study for the exam."

But why is it also wrong to use と in the sentence above if it is a "defining or quotative" particle?

---

Here is my interpretation of the answer to [the post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8278/is-%E6%84%9F%E3%81%98%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%93%E3%81%98%E3%82%8B-transitive-or-intransitive-which-particle-to-use) but I am not too confident, correct me if I'm wrong (I numbered my questions in this section respectively):

**を** can only be used in circumstances where the person has a:

- physical sense: e.g. 揺れるの**を**感じた、風**を**感じる
- spider sense: e.g. 将来に不安**を**感じる、彼は生命の危険**を**感じた

**と** is used as a "quotation/sound or manner adverbial" phrase

(I have trouble understanding how と particle is used the most)

- Used as a spider sense: 彼は何かを隠している**と**感じた (`2.` does this mean that 彼は何かを隠しているの**を**感じた is also correct?)

`3.`But what about this sentence? Is に or を also correct in this case?

> 良書を読むというも幸せ**と**感じる。I feel content in reading good books.

`4.`What are other cases where you can only use the と particle with 感じる?

**に** (or i-adjectives + く) is only used as an adverb to express emotional sense

- その時，初めて母の愛を深**く**感じた。

と cannot be used with verbs that only express a knowledge/forgetting of facts. e.g. 忘れる、思い出す、知る.

But it can be used with verbs that can express feeling or belief e.g. 分かる、信じる、思う、考える

However, considering something from my [previous post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57038/how-is-%E3%81%A8-used-in-these-sentences/57050?noredirect=1#comment98728_57050)

> 私はあなたがいつも忙しい**と**分かっています。

`5.`Would it be incorrect to use the adverb rule as stated above?

> 私はあなたがいつも忙し**く**分かっています。

---

I might have answered my own question already but I am still not too confident of my interpretation. I would appreciate further clarification on how these particles are used with these kinds of verbs, and some examples would be great.

Apologies for the long post, I did my best to keep it as brief and organized as I could. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

残念に感じる and 残念(だ)と感じる are basically interchangeable. They both mean "to feel it's regrettable" rather than "to regrettably feel something". This 残念に is "adverbial" in a broad sense, but it does not describe the way 感じる happens. Japanese "adverbial" modifiers do not necessarily work the same way as English adverbs (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55796/5010), too). In this case, maybe you can think of this に as a rough equivalent of English "as", e.g., 候補者に選ぶ ("to choose *as* a candidate"), 教師に採用する ("to recruit *as* a teacher"), 枕によい ("to serve well *as* a pillow").

Note that adjectives before に感じる/思う can work in two different ways, depending on the word.

> - 奇妙に感じる, 変に感じる, 残念に思う, 遺憾に思う, 悲しく思う, ありがたく思う...
>     I feel/think it's *strange/pitiful/sad/etc...*
> - 痛切に感じる, 強く思う, ...
>     I *strongly/deeply/etc* feel/think ...
> - よく思う (ambiguous) I think it's good / I often think ...

---

- 本を読むと幸せに感じる and 本を読むと幸せと感じる are interchangeable.
- 母の愛を深く感じた only means "I *deeply* felt mother's love". This 深く is a simple adverbial modifier.
- Please do not overly generalize the use of ～に感じる/～に思う. 忙しく考える only means "to think busily/hard about something". 忙しく分かる/信じる makes almost no sense to me.

Comment: This is unrelated, but why is だ optional here (before と).

Comment: @Simon I think see e.g. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/82906/dropping-%e3%81%a0-in-sentences