# 不思議に思う meaning/grammar

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

In my text book I have the sentence
「どうして神様や仏様を同時に祭ることができるのか不思議に思うかもしれない」
Does this translate to “how can they worship both Buddha and other gods at the same time, they will think strangely”.
When I typed in 不思議 to my online dictionary it gave me a bunch of answers which to me some were completely different from the rest. When I google translated it i was told it means “to wonder”.
Can someone shed a little light on this for me .
Thanks!

Comment: 不思議 is a simple adjective meaning "mysterious/strange", but ～に思う/～く思う has a little tricky usage. Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57217/5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While 不思議 itself has a few different usages, the set phrase 不思議に思う generally means 'to wonder' or 'to wonder why' (when どうして is included). You could say that the literal meaning is 'to think of as being strange', but that can sound a little strong.

So the elements of your translation are intact but instead of 'think strangely', I would use 'wonder why'. More context about who is doing the wondering would be helpful, but I would translate as follows:

> どうして神様や仏様を同時に祭ることができるのか不思議に思うかもしれない。
> (Somebody) might wonder how they are able to worship both God and Buddha at the same time.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you also perhaps explain the meanings of 不思議? If it’s not too mich trouble!!

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%8D%E6%80%9D%E8%AD%B0