# って role in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-って

Why is the って used in this sentence?

> どんな時に幸せって感じますか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

って here is an informal way of saying と. Have a look at the answer in this thread:

[Confusion with に、を、と particles used with verbs like 感じる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57217/confusion-with-%E3%81%AB-%E3%82%92-%E3%81%A8-particles-used-with-verbs-like-%E6%84%9F%E3%81%98%E3%82%8B)