# Nounに感じる vs. Nounを感じる

Tags: particle-に, particle-を

Can anyone explain me what are the differences between `Nounに感じる` and `Nounを感じる`. I currently understand `Nounを感じる` as "To feel Noun", but I don't know what's `Nounに感じる`. For an example:

> こんなにも近くに感じてる (It's from a song)

Comment: Partly related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57217/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8278/9831

Answer (score 2):

In your example, 近く is a noun that means a close place, and に indicates a point where the target of perception exists. So, it technically means that you feel something at a close place. However, it seems more like saying something feels close to you, which is the same as …を近く感じる, actually, assuming a cliche.

This structure, I mean, Xを Yに 感じる (or other verbs of perception) has another meaning, like others say. You can compare something to something else. e.g. それを問題に感じる: I find that it's a problem / I find it problematic

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. May I ask you another question in the same topic ?  I have known that the place where an action made uses で. Like 近くで感じる.  Or is に usable too ? Thanks anyway !

Comment: That's different. で indicates a place where the speaker stands. For example, when you are in your home and your lover is in a neiborhood, で indicates your home while に does the neighborhood.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking about it whole day.     May I ask for my sureness. Does it mean like “I feel X(を) as Y(に). 近くに感じてる means I feel something (that’s omitted in the sentence) to be near place. Thank you.

Comment: Yes............